# Are there HTTP header fields I could use to spot spam bots?

Tags: php, http-headers, spam-prevention, bots

It stands to reason that scrapers and spambots wouldn't be built as well as normal web browsers. With this in mind, it seems like there should be some way to spot blatant spambots by just looking at the way they make requests.

Are there any methods for analyzing HTTP headers or is this just a pipe-dream?

```
Array
(
    [Host] => example.com
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Referer] => http://example.com/headers/
    [Cache-Control] => max-age=0
    [Accept] => application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
    [Accept-Charset] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
)
```

Comment: Only a few bots have reliable signatures. Most form spam crawlers perform replay attacks or are ActiveX zombies. (But very much depends on the target site.) `Referer`-linkbots are becoming rare. But look into "bad behaviour".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were writing a spam bot, I would fake the headers of a normal browser, so I doubt this is a viable approach.  Some other suggestions that might help

Instead

- use a captcha
- if that's too annoying, a simple but effective trick is to include a text input which is hidden by a CSS rule; users won't see it, but spam bots won't normally bother to parse and apply all the CSS rules, so they won't realise the field is not visible and will put something in it.  Check on form submission that the field is empty and disregard it if it is.
- use a nonce on your forms; check that the nonce that was used when you rendered the form is the same as when it's submitted.  This won't catch everything, but will ensure that the post was at least made by something that received the form in the first place.  Ideally change the nonce every time the form is rendered.

Comment: nonce = *number used once*. A nonce *needs* to change every time or it's not a nonce. Otherwise, +1. :)

Comment: You are, of course, correct :)  However doing it incorrectly and reusing it until the form is successfully submitted (e.g. if they hit reload) is still better than not doing it at all, so I say ideally; in this case it is used once per form submission, rather than once per form view.

Comment: Using a nonce or "form token" also protects against CSFR. Never show a form without one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find all bots this way, but you could catch some, or at least get some probability of UA being a bot and use that with conjunction with another method.

Some bots forget about `Accept-Charset` and `Accept-Encoding` headers. You may also find impossible combinations of `Accept` and `User-Agent` (e.g. IE6 won't ask for XHTML, Firefox doesn't advertise MS Office types).

When blocking, be careful about proxies, because they could modify the headers. I recommend backing off if you see `Via` or `X-Forwarded-For` headers.

Ideally, instead of writing rules manually, you could use bayesian classifier. It could be as simple as joining relevant headers together and using them as a single "word" in the classifier.